# Using ContextInjectionFactory with Type <T>

Tags: java, dependency-injection, rcp

What is the correct way to use DependencyInjection /  ContextInjectionFactory without generating a type safety warning?

```
 public class MyClass<T> {...}

 // Without Dependency Injection
 MyClass<MyType> x = new MyClass<MyType>();

 // With Dependency Injection and TypeSafety warning
 MyClass<MyType> x = ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyClass.class, context);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to have to use the wild card generic `<?>`.

```
MyClass<?> x = ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyClass.class, context);
```

This will remove the warning but then all generic methods will only work with `Object`. One way around this is to cast `x` to `MyType`.

```
MyClass<MyType> myClass = (MyClass<MyType>) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard to avoid generating a type safety warning:-

```
MyClass<?> x = ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyClass.class, context);
```